# Is it possible to inject a class into the executing assembly at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, codedom, runtime-compilation

I am experimenting with the CSharpCodeProvider .NET Code DOM class an I am able to compile an assembly and create an instance defined within the assembly, but I'm interested to know whether it is possible to 'inject' code or rather a class into a namespace within the executing assembly.

I could possibly work around the problem by compiling the code into an assembly file however I would like to do this in memory if possible.

Comment: Have you looked at anything like `Spring.Net` it handles `dependency Injection`

Comment: I would like to do this without resorting to any external frameworks libraries etc. Thanks though.

Comment: You can't add code to an existing assembly. You *can* however, compile to an in-memory assembly (i.e. never write it to disk). Look at the `CompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.generateinmemory.aspx

Comment: Assembly != namespace. You can add to the namespace after the fact, so to speak, but (probably) not an assembly, so Jim's suggestion should work for you.

Comment: Got there in the end, thanks.